# Is the Time and date slider in alpacajs available or how can we develop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, alpacajs

Alpaca gives the number slider but is there any way to create a time slider using AlpacaJS? I have tried number slider with `slider=true` property but it didn't work.

And as I am new to alpacajs I don't know the way to customize this field in alpacajs.

Code for this used which didn't work is:

```
'from - to':
{
'type': 'utc-datetime',
'label': 'From',
'picker': datetimeUtils.pickerDefault,
'slider': true
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing using jQuery slider, but I don't know how to convert javascript code into alpaca form and how to use it in apaca UI.

Here is the javascript code:

```
;(function() {
"use strict";

function dateFormat(date, fmt) {
    var o = {
        "M+": date.getMonth() + 1,
        "d+": date.getDate(),
    };
    if (/(y+)/.test(fmt)){
        fmt = fmt.replace(RegExp.$1, (date.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
    }
    for (var k in o) {
        if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(fmt)){
            fmt = fmt.replace(RegExp.$1, (RegExp.$1.length === 1) ? (o[k]) : (("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length)));
        }
    }
    return fmt;
}

var startDate = new Date("2001/11/12 00:00:00"),
    endDate = new Date("2040/12/22 00:00:00"),
    offset = endDate - startDate;

$("#date_range").rangepicker({
    startValue: dateFormat(startDate, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
    endValue: dateFormat(endDate, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
    translateSelectLabel: function(currentPosition, totalPosition) {
        var timeOffset = offset * ( currentPosition / totalPosition);
        var date = new Date(+startDate + parseInt(timeOffset));
        return dateFormat(date, "yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
});

$("#double_date_range").rangepicker({
    type: "double",
    startValue: dateFormat(startDate, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
    endValue: dateFormat(endDate, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
    translateSelectLabel: function(currentPosition, totalPosition) {
        var timeOffset = offset * ( currentPosition / totalPosition);
        var date = new Date(+startDate + parseInt(timeOffset));
        return dateFormat(date, "yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am now trying to use the jquery plugin for date range picker but dont know how to coonvert javascript code into alpaca form. :